# How to count variable +1 in Liquid

Tags: ruby, liquid

I am completely stumped by how to count plus one towards a variable assigned via `{% assign var = 0 %}`. It should be the most simple task. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
{% assign amount = 0 %}
{% for variant in product.variants %}
    {% assign amount = amount + 1 %}
{% endfor %}

Amount: {{ amount }}
```

The result is always `0`. Maybe I'm overlooking something obvious. Maybe there is a better way altogether. All I want to archive is getting the number of iterations that are run.

Comment: Does the loop even run? You are sure of that?

Comment: Yes, when I assign `1` within the loop, I get `1`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As `{{ increment amount }}` will output your variable value and **does not affect a variable defined by `{% assign %}`**, I suggest you to use `{% capture %}`:

```
{% assign amount = 0 %}
{% for variant in product.variants %}
    {% capture amount %}{{ amount | plus:1 }}{% endcapture %}
{% endfor %}

Amount: {{ amount }}
```

I agree this is verbose, but it's AFAIK the only working solution.

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me and is a bit less verbose:

```
{% assign amount = 0 %}
{% for variant in product.variants %}
  {% assign amount = amount | plus:1 %}
{% endfor %}
```

Further, it looks like `capture` returns a string instead of an integer, making it necessary to cast `amount` to an integer if you want to do something like `{{if amount >= 10}}`.